# Regarding connectedness of the space $X$

Tags: general-topology

Let $m>1$ be a positive integer consider the equivalence relation on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ as $z_1\sim z_2$ $\iff$ $z_1=z_2e^\frac{2\pi ia}{m}$ for some $a\in \mathbb Z$. Let, $X$ be the set of the equvalance classes and $p: \mathbb C\setminus \{0\} \to X$ is a map takes $z$ to its equvalance class. Let us define a topology on $X$ by $U\subset X \iff p^{-1}(U)$ is open with respect to Euclidean topology in $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Determine whether  $X$ is (1) Compact (2) Hausdorff (3) Connected?

My attempts:

(1)$X$ is not compact. Let us take $A_n=\{z\in \mathbb C : |z|<n\}$. Clearly $A_n$ is open in $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ and $\bigcup_nA_n$ is the open cover for $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ but can not attain finite subcover. And it is clear that for $z_1\sim z_2 \implies |z_1|=|z_2|$. So, for $z_1<n\implies z_2<n$. Now, $p^{-1}p(A_n)=A_n$. So, from the definition of open set in $X$ we can say that $p(A_n)$ is open in X $\iff$ $p^{-1}p(A_n)=A_n$ is open in $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$. So, $\bigcup_np(A_n)$ is the open cover for $X$ but can not admit finite subcover so, $X$ is not compact.

(2) $X$ is Hausdorff because we know equivalence relation partitioned set in some disjoint pieces so for this let $z_1,z_2\in \mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ and $z_1\neq z_2$ we shall get the two classes $[z_1],[z_2]\in X$. Clarly, $[z_1]\cap [z_2]=\emptyset$. Let us take $U_1,U_2$ be the two open sets containing $[z_1],[z_2]$ respectively so, $z\in p^{-1}(U_1)$ and $z_2\in p^{-1}(U_2)$. Since $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is Hausdorff so $z\in p^{-1}(U_1) \cap z_2\in p^{-1}(U_2)=\emptyset$ so $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset$. So we are done!

But now I am stuck. I can not understand that how to show $X$ is connected or not. It is not pathconnected it is clear beacause of the partition.

Any hints regarding connectednedd will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Re connectedness, $\mathbb C - \{0\}$ is connected. What does that say about its continuous image via $p$?

Comment: @AymanHourieh OK! Because $p$ is onto so image of connecetd set is connected. But I have a small doubt about "Path connectedness". By the same logic $p(\mathbb C - \{0\})=X$ and $\mathbb C - \{0\}$ is path connected so $X$ is. But is $X$ path connected?

Comment: $X$ is indeed path-connected, as your comment proves.

Comment: OK, sir thank you very much. Sir, is my proof of non-compactness correct?